# Is there any Android API available to read info about the crash of third-party apps on the device?

Tags: android

I want to get the info about the crash that was reported in other apps on the device.
I tried with UncaughtExceptionHandler but it will handle only the current app, not the other apps on the device.

**I need to get a callback when a third-party app crashes on the device.**

Any idea how to get the info about the crash in other apps?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the firebase crashlytics in your application to get the details about the crashes.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics

If it is not useful please drop a comment. Thank you.

Comment: If we include Crashlytics Can we get crash details of third-party apps on the device?

Comment: Whichever project you have, if you include crashlytics you can able to mange the crashes in the Firebase console itself.

Comment: I need to get a callback in my application when we get a crash in other applications on the device, not in console.